# LWC lightning-button-menu alignment

Tags: lightning, slds, lightning-web-components

I use `lightning-button-menu` component and would like to align the menu top.
I found that it can be aligned left or right, but it there a possibility to align top?

```
<lightning-button-menu alternative-text="Export options"
                       variant="bare"
                       icon-name="utility:threedots_vertical"
                       menu-alignment="right">
     <lightning-menu-item value="pfd" 
                          label="Export to PDF">
     </lightning-menu-item>
     <lightning-menu-item value="xls" 
                          label="Export to Excel">
     </lightning-menu-item>
</lightning-button-menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do it. The Lightning Design System specified this functionality:
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/#Positioned-Bottom

and also the mentioned LWC component implemented it too:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonMenu/specification

You need to use either bottom-left, bottom-center or bottom-right values in the menu-alignment argument.

Comment: ohh thanks. I did not read the docs properly.